# AngularJS - To Do App Place Submit and Delete Function into Factories

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've created a simple To Do App and while working on it I felt like I will end up placing too much code into my Controller and will eventually get messy and hard to read. I want to know how can I move my functions into factories so that my code can look somewhat cleaner.

Here is my JS:

```
angular.module('toDoApp', [])
    .controller('toDoCtrl', function($scope){
        //set $scope variables
        $scope.tasks = [];
        $scope.submitTask = function(){
            $scope.tasks.unshift($scope.enteredTask); 
            $scope.enteredTask = '';
        };
        $scope.removeTask = function(task) {
            var i = $scope.tasks.indexOf(task);
            $scope.tasks.splice(i, 1);
        };
    })
    .factory('toDoFactory', ['$http', function($http){
        return function(newTask) {

        };
    }])
```

Here is the HTML if needed:

```
<form ng-submit="submitTask()">
    <!-- task input with submit button -->
    <label>Task: </label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Task" ng-model="enteredTask" required>
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
<div>
    <!-- create unordered list for task that are submitted 
        need check boxes -->
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="task in tasks">
            {{ task }}
            <button ng-click="removeTask()">x</button>
        </li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

As you can see I kinda started the factory but just don't know how to go about it.
Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the fast replies ashfaq.p and @Raja Sekar. I think I got it figured out from your guy's responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to inject your factory inside controller and then use the methods defined in the factory from the controller:

```
angular.module('toDoApp', [])
.controller('toDoCtrl', function($scope, toDoFactory){
    //set $scope variables
    $scope.tasks = [];
    $scope.submitTask = function(){
        toDofactory.submittask(); //Just for demo.Passin your parameters based on your implementation
    };
    $scope.removeTask = function(task) {
        var i = $scope.tasks.indexOf(task);
        $scope.tasks.splice(i, 1);
    };
})
.factory('toDoFactory', ['$http', function($http){
    var methods = {};
    methods.submittask = function(){
        //your logic here
    };
    methods.removetask = function(){
      //your logic here
    }
    return methods;
}])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var app = angular.module('toDoApp', []);

app.controller('toDoCtrl', function($scope, toDoFactory){
        $scope.tasks = [];
        toDoFactory.get = function(){

        }
        toDoFactory.delete = function(){

        }
        toDoFactory.update = function(){

        }
});

app.factory('toDoFactory', ['$http', function($http){
        var todo = {};
        todo.get = function(){

        };

        todo.delete = function(){

        };

        todo.update = function(){

        }

        return todo;

}]);
```

This is simple architecture, you can add more logic, 
Make sure you know about dependency injection(DI)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer for those that want to see what the end result will look like when all the code is plugged in. Thanks again for the answers as it was able to guide me in the right direction.

```
.controller('toDoCtrl', function($scope, toDoFactory){
    $scope.tasks = toDoFactory.tasks;
    $scope.submitTask = function(){
        toDoFactory.submitTask($scope.enteredTask); 
        $scope.enteredTask = '';
    };
    $scope.removeTask = function(task) {
        toDoFactory.removeTask();
    };
})
.factory('toDoFactory', ['$http', function($http){
    var toDo = {
        tasks: [],
        enteredTask: '',
        submitTask: function(task){
            toDo.tasks.unshift(task);
        },
        removeTask: function(task) {
            var i = toDo.tasks.indexOf(task);
            toDo.tasks.splice(i, 1);
        }
    };
}])
```